# Unique Constraint exception after dropping constraint

Tags: oracle, index, unique-constraint

We had dropped a unique constraint using the ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT script, but it is still throwing the Unique Constraint exception while trying to insert. We drilled this down to two possible reasons.

1. Having the Unique Constraint with the same name under other schemas. We had deleted from USER_CONSTRAINTS so that it is deleted from the current scheme. Do we need to delete it from ALL_CONSTRAINTS? This is the only difference from the Test and Development Environment, where it worked fine.
2. Not dropping the index. This was not carried out in the development environment, but still the Unique Constraint Exception was not thrown.

We are using Oracle 11g. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: most likely you didn't drop the index associated with the constraint.

Comment: @Raj Exactly, we could find that is the issue, index not being dropped. But then in development environment, the index got dropped automatically with the constraint, but not in test. Any idea on why this might be occurring?

Comment: possibly in dev environment, the constraint was created which in turn created the unique index. In prod, probably a unique index existed and a constraint was created using that index?